# I want to dynamically change resultset column names

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to change column names in resultset, dynamically adding the year from sysdate.

So I've tried something like this:

```
create table TestTable (
      name varchar2(30),
      age  INTEGER
);

insert into TestTable values('johnny1',10);
insert into TestTable values('johnny2',15);

Select qry0.name,qry0.age as to_char("age" || qry1.theyear)
from (Select name,age from TestTable) qry0,
     (select to_char(sysdate,('YYYY'))as TheYear from dual)qry1;
```

I trying to get column headers like this:

```
NAME    AGE2019
```

Thanks

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL if you want variable column names.  In Oracle, that means using `execute immediate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using something like SQLPlus to generate your report, and you are just looking an appropriate name in your report, you could use a substitution variable, eg

```
SQL> create table TestTable (
  2        name varchar2(30),
  3        age  INTEGER
  4  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into TestTable values('johnny1',10);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into TestTable values('johnny2',15);

1 row created.

SQL> col xx new_value yy
SQL> select 'AGE'||to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') xx from dual;

XX
-------
AGE2019

SQL> select name, age &&yy from testtable;

NAME                              AGE2019
------------------------------ ----------
johnny1                                10
johnny2                                15
```

Comment: Thanks Connor looks like what I'm looking for alright but I'm using Toad and it wont run the first statement 'col xx new_value yy'